# Mod_Rewrite for CDN

Tags: mod-rewrite

I need a Mod_Rewrite rule that will re-direct all references in our web app to a CDN URL instead of loading the images from /img on the localhost.  Does anyone have a sample Mod_Rewrite code snippet that would accomplish this?  Thanks so much!  John

Answer (score 1):

ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse are your friends

```
ProxyPass /img/  http://cdn/imageslocation/
ProxyPassReverse /img/ http://cdn/imageslocation/
```

Comment: This doesn't really *redirect* the request though, does it? THis actually proxies it through, which I don't think is what the OP wants.

Comment: @Pekka True, that would take a 302 and some logic. not sure what OP was referring to though, so I gave him the simpler solution.